# PHP mysqli_fetch_array supposedly getting a boolean

Tags: php

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Players");
if ($result !== FALSE) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE Players SET Score='$score' WHERE ID='$id'");
    }
}
```

This **works**. That is, the databse is indeed updated and everything is all cool.

But it throws a warning:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given

If you search around, the explanation is that the query is failing - hence, it is returning `FALSE`, so you get the warning.

... But this doesn't make sense in my case. The query **is not failing**. When I run this script, my database is updated just fine. Besides, there is also a conditional checking if the result is a boolean *before* using `mysqli_fetch_array`, so technically this warning should never happen in the first place.

Whatever, the problem must be with `$result`. Let's do:

```
echo gettype($result);
```

Which results in

> "object"

Well, this explains why is it passing the condition. However, this still won't explain why `mysqli_fetch_array` insists this is a boolean (because it isn't).

What is the problem, then?

Tested with PHP Version 5.3.24 and 5.4.19.

Comment: You reset the `$result` With an UPDATE query. Which is not a resultset. Change the variable name.

Comment: Depending on how important the UPDATE query is, you don't need to story it in a result set since no result set is returned from an update query. If you need to know if the query worked correctly, check it directly in an if like: `if(mysqli_query(...))`. What exactly is your query trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're overwriting the resultset `$result` from your SELECT query with a new `$result` value from the UPDATE query inside your loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE Players SET Score='$score' WHERE ID='$id'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The $result array returns nothing when you are updating the table. That's why, you are getting this warning in the while loop when it is trying to fetch data from $result into $row.

Answer (score 1):

In while loop used Same variable name '$result' which are already used before. Change variable name inside loop.

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE Players SET Score='$score' WHERE ID='$id'");
    }